# Compare two files line by line in scala

Tags: file, scala, compare

I have 2 files,
file1:

```
1
2
0
2
1
2
3
2
...
```

and file2:

```
1
2
2
2
1
1
2
1
...
```

how can i compare these two files line by line? i want to count lines which have same values. for example in two above files:

```
1=1
2=2
0!=2
2=2
...
```

i've tried:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val lines = fromFile("data/file1.txt").getLines
    val lines2 = fromFile("data/file2.txt").getLines
    var l = 0
    var cnt = 0
    for (line <- lines) {
      for (line2<-lines2){

        if (line == line2){
          cnt += 1
        }
      }

      println(cnt)

    }
  }
```

but i doesn't show my favorite output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nesting the iterations, i.e. you compare line 1 of the first file against *all* lines of the second file, then line 2 of the first file against all lines of the second file… Not even that because `getLines` gives you an iterator which will be exhausted after the first loop.

The easiest would be

```
(lines1 zip lines2).count { case (a, b) => a == b }
```

Comment: Make sure to replace this with `zipAll(lines2, "", "")` if files are not equal length. zip may give wrong results if the two files don't have the same length, and zipall makes the two iterators the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert to Arrays and compare them

```
lines1.toArray.sameElements(lines2.toArray)
```

It will return boolean.